# MYSQL Query for sorting wordpress usermeta data

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sorting, metadata

Hi i am trying to do a query against the wordpress usermeta database to get all users that have a custom meta_name and value assigned. The custom name/value is a score (integer). I need to bring back the users with the highest score and limit the query to 5 results.

I have a working statement but it doest want to sort them properly.

```
$gather_top_users = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta WHERE meta_key='points' ORDER BY meta_value DESC LIMIT 5 ";
```

Any ideas why this is not properly sorting them in the array?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to cast it to an integer first i.e.

```
ORDER BY CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC
```

See [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@estern:**

WordPress' `meta_value` field is `longtext` so it won't sort as a number unless you convert it into one so change your `ORDER BY` from this:

```
ORDER BY meta_value DESC
```

To this:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(meta_value,UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Hope this helps.

-Mike

P.S. You might want to check out StackOverflow's sister site [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) next time you need help with WordPress. Lots of WordPress enthusiasts are on hand over there to answer your WordPress questions.